# stylesheet_pack_tag not finding app/javascript/src/application.css in rails 5.1 with webpacker gem

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-5, webpacker

I am receiving this error when I try to load a page in my new rails 5.1 app using webpacker. I would like webpacker to handle CSS as well.

```
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2017-09-01 12:20:23 -0400
Processing by HomeController#welcome as HTML
  Rendering home/welcome.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered home/welcome.html.erb within layouts/application (0.4ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 28ms



ActionView::Template::Error (Webpacker can't find application.css in /Users/myusername/Documents/testing-ground/myapp/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:
1. You want to set wepbacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
   unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
2. Webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
4. Your Webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
Your manifest contains:
{
  "application.js": "/packs/application-1ba6db9cf5c0fb48c785.js",
  "hello_react.js": "/packs/hello_react-812cbb4d606734bec7a9.js"
}
):
     7:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
     8:     <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
     9:     <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
    10: <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application' %>
    11:   </head>
    12:
    13:   <body>

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:10:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__1178607493020013329_70339213085820'
```

I am running the `./bin/webpack-dev-server` alongside the `rails server`. I created the app using:

`rails new myapp --webpack` 
`bundle`
`bundle exec rails webpacker:install:react`

I have a single CSS file `app/javascript/src/application.css`. (Writing that makes me feel something is wrong. Putting css inside of a javascript directory seems improper.)

I just have single root route defined `root to: 'home#welcome'`.

Here is `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Myapp</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
    <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my `config/webpacker.yml` (I have tried also setting compile to `false` in development.

```
# Note: You must restart bin/webpack-dev-server for changes to take effect

default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  resolved_paths: []

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: false

  extensions:
    - .coffee
    - .erb
    - .js
    - .jsx
    - .ts
    - .vue
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  dev_server:
    host: localhost
    port: 3035
    hmr: false
    https: false

test:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Compile test packs to a separate directory
  public_output_path: packs-test

production:
  <<: *default

  # Production demands on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: false

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true
```

I don't want to add too many details up-front incase they are more distracting then helpful. Please ask for anything else and I'll add to my question. Thanks!

Comment: how did you solve this?

Comment: This may help anyone in the future https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58506351/webpacker-throws-application-css-not-found-in-manifest-json-in-rails-6-applica

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In your application.js :

```
import "path to application.css"
```

Comment: Great answer. It's amazing this isn't documented somewhere.

Comment: This solve the problem also for me... but why I need to add this line in my `application.js` ??

Comment: You can [check this out in the Webpacker docs here](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/css.md#css-sass-and-scss).

Answer (score 9):

I had this exact problem, on Rails 5.2 with Webpack's current version as of Dec 5, 2018 (4.2.x?) and just resolved it.

The fix for me was renaming `application.css` to anything else.  I think there was a naming collision with Webpack.

So now my pack tags look like:

```
<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'styles', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

I did NOT need to `import` the stylesheet inside `application.js`.  This appears to make no difference for me.

**OPTIONAL BONUS:**  I also renamed the `app/javascript` to `app/webpack` because I also thought it was confusing to run styles out of a Javascript directory (and learned from this youtube video that it could be done: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I_GGYIWbmg0&feature=youtu.be&t=32m35s).  Simply:

1. Rename the directory to `app/webpack`
2. Adjust `webpacker.yml` like so:  `source_path: app/webpack`

Hope that helps.

Comment: I also had to change the file extension to something other than `.css` (e.g. `.scss`). Otherwise Webpack would list it as `.js` in the manifest file.

Comment: Man thank you for this! I just had to rename my file. It's now `base.css`

Answer (score 3):

When HMR is set to false the styles are inlined within the bundle so you won't get any css bundle. 
In your webpacker.yml file, setting hmr to true should fix your problem.
I realize this is an old question.  Relevant, though.

Answer (score 1):

In "config/environments/production.rb":

```
config.public_file_server.enabled = true
```

Delete "public/assets" and "public/pack"

And run:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it with running `yarn add postcss-smart-import` in console.

upd: rails 5.2, webpacker 3.5, default config.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem or Rails 6.0.3.1.
I updated the file app/assets/config/manifest.js

```
//= link_directory ../../javascript/packs
//= link_directory ../images
```

Then restart in your terminal:

```
bin/webpack-dev-server
```

Answer (score 0):

I had such problem even with `import "path/to/application.css"` line in `application.js`

In my case it was because test assets was precompiled with different node version

node modules was installed with node version v12
but test assets was compiled with with node version v10

assets were compiled but when I've looked inside `public/pack-test/application.[hash].js` and grep `application.scss` I saw an error line about `node-sass` missing.

In my cause problem was with Rubymine IDE - it somehow cache $PATH value from time when I had default node version v10 in nvm.

I hope my store will have somebody, who will encounter similar issue in future.

Answer (score 0):

### Revise Insallation Guide

Revise the version of webpacker (in `package.json` and `Gemfile.lock` with git story) if had recent changes withou you concerns.

All major errors are fixed when you revise: [installation official guide](https://github.com/rails/webpacker#installation)

For me, **for example**, after revised I needed to add some files in `/packs/application.js`, include this at the top of the file:

```
import 'core-js/stable'
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime'
```

Answer (score 0):

I cleared webpacker's cache and it started working again for me:

`rm -rf tmp/cache/webpacker`